# Error In $http PUT

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm building a simple auction site. I showed my products in the page. Now i wanna make a new offer. in my controller i use ng-dialog to open a pop-up form and i pass inside the auction that i need. like this:

```
     $scope.clickToOpen4 = function (followingauction) {

    console.log(followingauction.allbids[followingauction.allbids.length -1].bid);
    var newScope = $scope.$new();
    newScope.auction = followingauction;
    ngDialog.open({template: '../views/partials/offer.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        scope: newScope
    });
};
```

In my template offer.html i have a simple form:

```
      <form name="Offer"  ng-controller="FollowingAuctionsController">
Your Offer:<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="Your Offer" ng-model="newOffer" name="new offer" required> €<br>

<input class="btn" type="submit" ng-click="submitNewOffer(auction._id, auction.allbids[auction.allbids.length -1].bid)" value="OK"><br>
```

And in the submitNewOffer i pass, the id of the auction and the highest offer.

And this is the submitnewOffer():

```
     $scope.submitNewOffer = function (id, bid) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(bid);
    var newBid = $scope.newOffer;
    if (newBid>bid) {
        console.log(newBid);
        console.log('/api/followingauctions/newoffer/' + id);
        $http.put('/api/followingauctions/newoffer/' + id, newBid)
            .then(function () {
                alert('Offert Done!');
                getFollowingAuctions();
            });
    }

    else {
        alert('The offer must be higher!');
        $scope.newOffer = '';
    }
};
```

Like you see i do the console.log to see if the data that i passed into the template are ok. They are!
Than if the new bid is less than the highest bid that i passed, i send that alert, else i put the new offer.

All works fine and all the console.log are fine. But when i submit the newBid (that is higher than the old bid) it send me this error:

angular.js:12578 PUT http://localhost:3001/api/followingauctions/newoffer/58dbd190b8042b080d1418bf 400 (Bad Request)

angular.js:14516 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"

## Unexpected token 8

### 400

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 8\n    at parse (/Users/m.pagano/WebstormProjects/Challenge_2/Project2/sampsite/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)\n    at /Users/m.pagano/WebstormProjects/Challenge_2/Project2/sampsite/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18\n    at invokeCallback (/Users/m.pagano/WebstormProjects/Challenge_2/Project2/sampsite/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)\n    at done (/Users/m.pagano/WebstormProjects/Challenge_2/Project2/sampsite/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/m.pagano/WebstormProjects/Challenge_2/Project2/sampsite/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)\n    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

","status":400,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/followingauctions/newoffer/58dbd190b8042b080d1418bf","data":800,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Bad Request"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the method incorrectly.

The right signature of `$http.put` method is `put(url, data, [config]);`

So, your code could look like this:

```
$http.put('/api/followingauctions/newoffer/' + id, {newBid: newBid})
        .then(function () {
            // success
        });
```

and you can access `newBid` from `POST` at the backend

OR

```
$http.put('/api/followingauctions/newoffer/' + id, {}, {params: {newBid: newBid}})
        .then(function () {
            // success
        });
```

in which case, `newBid` can be obtained from `GET` at the backend

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

When doing a PUT request with $http, you have to specify the `params`:

```
$http.put('/api/followingauctions/newoffer/' + id, {}, params: {'newBid': newBid})
    .then(function () {
        alert('Offert Done!');
        getFollowingAuctions();
});
```